# CSS stylesheet not available in tomcat

Tags: html, css, tomcat

I created a maven-webapp project in eclipse and want to put a css stylesheet on my .jsp site, but my tomcat keeps saying that "The requested source is not available".

This is my .jsp file (also tried to add the absolute path to the file...):

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/index1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/WEB-INF/pages/index1.css"><title>Simple Form Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>test</h1>
<h2>Simple Form Demosdds</h2>
 <div id="ololo" class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button"
    data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown Example <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

 <form name="myForm" action="result.jsp" method="post">
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>First Name:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="first" value="" size="50"></td>
    </tr>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Last Name:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="last" value="" size="50"></td>
    </tr>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Email:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50"></td>
    </tr>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Gender:</td>
     <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" />Male <input
      type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />Female</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><select name="state">
       <option value="">Choose a state...</option>
       <option value="IA">Ioaw</option>
       <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
       <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
       <option value="Other">Other</option>
     </select></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>

  <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="clear"> <input
   type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my .css file:

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

body {
    background-color: red;
}

h1 {
    color: navy;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

h2 {
    size: 220;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

#ololo {
 color: red;
}
```

When I start my tomcat 8 it looks like this:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCabU.png)

When I import the .css file directy into firefox, it works.

My structure is like this:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf9j6.png)

€: web.xml:

```html
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

 <display-name>Application</display-name>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
                        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>
                   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
                </listener-class>
 </listener>
</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.XXX.XXX.controller" />

 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: I worked on a velocity templated project a while ago the path included velocity/www so is yours not pages/www path?

Comment: could you please provide your `web.xml` file ?

Comment: Hey, this is no velocity templated project, just a standard maven project. I added the web.xml.

Comment: `resources/css/index1.css` should work

Comment: I tried to put it there in the first place, but it did not work. I have the same problem with .js files. The js works if I put it directly in the html code, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally I found the problem. I had to add the mvc:resources mapping to my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml.

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.xxx.controller" />

 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```